# How to subtract data from a column in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Good morning I would like if you can help me to make a query in SQL or Postgresql, I have a column with the following data

```
" | Old 0.00 New 50.2 F20190429093143 | Old 50.20 New 50.2 F20191111151118 | Old 50.20 New 50.2 F20191202110735 | Old 50.20 New 53.2 F20201124173459 | Old 53.2 New 158.63 F20201125093143"
```

What I want to get are the last 3 updates, that is, we show the last 3 " | Old ..." and I kept something like that

```
 | Old 50.20 New 50.2 F20191202110735 | Old 50.20 New 53.2 F20201124173459 | Old 53.2 New 158.63 F20201125093143
```

I can't think of how to make the query to get that value back

Comment: This is no way to use a database.  Please move away from storing pipe delimited data in your table.  Instead, get each pipe value onto a separate row, and go from there.

Comment: Is that really one long string with `|` as the delimiter? If that really is a single value, this is a horrible data model

Comment: Yes, I know, it is the base model that a programmer before me used, and it is a lot of trouble for me to change it

Comment: And how much trouble do you expect to eliminate by not changing it. Seems like it is already giving you trouble, and if not fixed it will continue to do so. A bad design never gets better if just left alone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you also have some unique key/column in your table, the following hack would achieve what you want:

```
with entries as (
  select t.id, 
         x.entry, 
         regexp_split_to_array(x.entry, '\s+') as items
  from horribly_designed_table t
    cross join regexp_split_to_table(t.line, '\s{0,1}\|\s*') as x(entry)
  where nullif(trim(x.entry),'') is not null  
), numbered as (
  select id, 
         entry, 
         to_timestamp(items[5], '"F"yyyymmddhh24miss') as ts,
         row_number() over (partition by id order by to_timestamp(items[5], '"F"yyyymmddhh24miss') desc) as rn
  from entries  
)
select id, string_agg(entry, ' | ' order by ts) filter (where rn <= 3) as new_line
from numbered
group by id;
```

The first CTE splits the line into multiple rows, one for each "entry". It also creates an array of the items for each entry.

The second CTE then uses a window function to calculate a rank based on the last "item" (converted to a timestamp).

And finally the "last 3 entry" for each ID are then aggregated back into a single line.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ff0fc8f307eba82f89334b6664815490)